# how to print watermark for all the Itextsharp pdf pages in wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf

am using Itextsharp pdf in wpf "window" My code is printing watermark only for specific page i need to print watermark for all the pages of pdf?

```
 FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("vid.Png", FileMode.Open);
 iTextSharp.text.Image JPG = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs1), ImageFormat.Png);

  //Scale image
  JPG.ScalePercent(30f);

  // Set position
   JPG.SetAbsolutePosition(130f, 240f);

   //Close Stream
   fs1.Close();
```

Comment: as shown "vid.Png" contain only 1 image, are you looping through all images?

Comment: Show more details here that could help the reader to address your issue.